# Need advice on what I am doing wrong

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters, return-value

I have been working this for a few days and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  The name and GPA print out fine, but I cannot get the last part of the program to print.  The bold portion will not print out.
Thank you

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class BookstoreCredit 
    {
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
    String studentName;
    double gradeAverage;
    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Student name: ");
    studentName = inputDevice.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter student GPA: ");
    gradeAverage = inputDevice.nextDouble();  
    }

   **public static void computeDiscount(String name, double gpa) 
   {
    double credits;
    credits = gpa * 10;
    System.out.println(name + "your GPA is " +
    gpa + "so your credit is $ ." + credits);

    }**

    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you are calling the method `computeDiscount`.

Answer (score 1):

The last part is a static method, and moreover, you are not calling it inside the main method, so that block can't execute. You can try to add this line after **gradeAverage = inputDevice.nextDouble();**

```
gradeAverage = inputDevice.nextDouble();
computeDiscount(studentName, gradeAverage);
```

Comment: Since when there is `this` in static methods?

Comment: haha, sorry my bad, you can remove `this` just method name, cuz static method. I updated